# Quiz project how save answer?

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

I have a quiz project.  I get answer and question id from answerlist. then I set answer and question in map. at result I want to post this map to controllerservelet. then I want to parse map and insert into mysql database.

js code:

```
function saveanswer() {

     var savemaplist = new Map();

     savemaplist.set("$('#t1').val()","$('#t1a').val()") ;
     savemaplist.set("$('#2').val()","$('#t2a').val()") ;
     savemaplist.set("$('#3').val()","$('#t3a').val()") ;
     savemaplist.set("$('#4').val()","$('#t4a').val()") ;
     savemaplist.set("$('#5').val()","$('#t5a').val()") ;
     savemaplist.set("$('#6').val()","$('#t6a').val()") ;

}
```

please advice me how post this map then parse in controllerservelet for insert to dao mysql?

Answer (score 0):

it is vary bad Approach to store Answer in java Script because we can access them from java console better save in Database As soon as submitted.

Comment: Dear Salman, i dont save answer in javacsript, i just set them on li tag for user view. and end the of the li tag i have save button. i want  onllick save button post with ajax all answer list insert mysql database.

Comment: $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("servlet",
    {
        que1: "ans1",
        que1: "ans1"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});